# Restrição em alteração de tabela com subquery

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

A [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-restrictions.html) do MySQL diz:

> you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery
>   *você não pode alterar uma tabela ao selecionar dados dela numa subquery*

Isso se aplica às operações de `DELETE`, `UPDATE` e `INSERT`. A solução geralmente é substituir a subquery por algo que dê o mesmo resultado, como um `JOIN`, ou vários.

Sei que o SQL Server não tem essa restrição. Quem souber sobre Postgres e Oracle diz aí nos comentários. Minha dúvida é: por que o MySQL tem essa restrição? O que eles fazem (ou deixam de fazer) para que isso não seja possível?

Comment: O MariaDB tem essa mesma restrição: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/subquery-limitations/

Comment: @VictorStafusa é porque o Maria DB é quase uma copia do mysql, a oracle comprou o mysql, ai a galera do mysql fez o Maria DB.

Comment: @WictorChaves Sim, exatamente. [O criador deles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Widenius) é pai de duas filhas (My e Maria) e de um filho (Max). E criou um Sistema Gerenciador de Banco de Dados para cada um deles (MySQL, MariaDB e MaxDB). Não é todo dia que se encontra um pai que faz isso por seus filhos, né?

Comment: Relacionado no SO internacional: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23853453/4438007

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O único dado mais próximo de uma explicação fornecido na [própria documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html) é de que a alteração funciona caso o registro venha de uma tabela "derivada", como no exemplo abaixo, e que isso se deve ao fato de o dado derivado estar materializado em tabela temporária:

> UPDATE t ... WHERE col = (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... FROM t...) AS dt ...);

Extrapolando a partir dessa informação, esse comportamento pode ser resultado da necessidade de evitar locks conflitantes. Um UPDATE a partir de um SELECT se torna impossível pois a engine não permite obter lock exclusivo para um registro que já está com lock de leitura em outra transação.

Pensando dessa forma o exemplo acima funciona porque, ao se deparar com um "sub-subselect", o otimizador decide [materializar a consulta](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-materialization.html) em tabela temporária: o registro que recebe lock de leitura é uma cópia, em outro local, daquele que receberá lock exlusivo para UPDATE, evitando conflito.

Dito isso, reconheço que esse quadro que criei não faz muito sentido =/. A [documentação do InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) é bem detalhada ao frisar que a engine suporta multiversionamento de tuplas e os quatro níveis de isolamento de lock, não tem por que não fazer esse tipo de operação normalmente como no PostgreSQL, Oracle e afins. Só posso crer que se trata de um resquício de implementação do MyISAM desde versões pré-5.5.5, visto que o único tipo de lock suportado por esta engine é o de tabela inteira.

Comment: Faz sentido, eu desconfiava dos engines de tabela mesmo. Pode ser uma opção consciente para manter a sintaxe compatível entre esses dois.

Answer (score 3):

Informix também tem essa restrição.

Eu diria que é por uma questão de implementação mesmo. No fundo no fundo é por conta do perigo de se entrar em um *loop* infinito.

Para evitar o erro, geralmente eu coloco os dados de input em uma tabela temporária e trabalho o `UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT` em cima dessa tabela temporária.

Comment: Concordo. Eu acrescentaria que os desenvolvedores/mantenedores do MySQL acharam por bem que fosse assim e não documentaram o porquê. Mas creio que o motivo seja o risco de entrar em loop infinito mesmo.

Comment: Isso está mais pra um comentário até porque é totalmente baseado em "achismo"

Comment: @Mateus É "achismo" baseado em pesquisa. Se vc tiver a documentação onde explica a questão, por favor, mande o link para que nós possamos saber.

Comment: Perfeito, @Dvdsamm.

Answer (score 0):

Por mais funções que o MySql tenha, ele foi criado para ser um banco leve, e querendo ou não ele sofreria algumas "perdas" diante dos seus concorrentes.

E a sua documentação explica esta falta da seguinte forma:

> In MySQL, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in
>   a subquery. This applies to statements such as DELETE, INSERT,
>   REPLACE, UPDATE, and (because subqueries can be used in the SET
>   clause) LOAD DATA INFILE.
>
> No MySQL, você não pode modificar uma tabela e selecionar da mesma
>   tabela em uma subconsulta. Isso se aplica a declarações como DELETE,
>   INSERT, REPLACE, UPDATE e (porque as subconsultas podem ser usadas na
>   cláusula SET) LOAD DATA INFILE.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html

Comment: Oi Wictor, obrigado pela resposta. Se o problema for de "peso", saberia dizer onde exatamente isso pesa, e por quê? Estou em busca de uma explicação mais técnica disso.

Answer (score 0):

Em resumo `Join` é o metodo mais "atual", a diferença é que o `join` tem muito mais otimizaçao  e velocidade do que a subquery.

> A LEFT [OUTER] JOIN can be faster than an equivalent subquery because
>   the server might be able to optimize it better—a fact that is not
>   specific to MySQL Server alone. Prior to SQL-92, outer joins did not
>   exist, so subqueries were the only way to do certain things. Today,
>   MySQL Server and many other modern database systems offer a wide range
>   of outer join types.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html

-

> As subquery são a maneira logicamente correta de resolver problemas
>   do formulário, "Obter fatos de A, condicionados aos fatos de B".
>   Nesses casos, faz sentido mais lógico para manter B em uma
>   subquery do que fazer uma associação. Também é mais seguro, em um
>   sentido prático, que você não precisa ser cauteloso sobre a obtenção
>   de fatos duplicados de A devido a múltiplas partidas contra B.
>
> Praticamente falando, no entanto, a resposta geralmente se resume ao
>   desempenho. Alguns otimizadores sugam limões quando recebem uma junção
>   vs uma subquery, e alguns sugam limões do outro lado, e isso é
>   específico optimiser-specific, DBMS-version-specific e query-specific.
>
> Historicamente, as uniões explícitas geralmente ganham, daí a
>   sabedoria estabelecida que se une é melhor, mas os otimizadores estão
>   melhorando o tempo todo, e então prefiro escrever as consultas
>   primeiro de uma maneira logicamente coerente e, em seguida,
>   reestruturo se as restrições de desempenho garantissem isso.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577188/5703284

Comment: Não é bem essa a pergunta, é sobre restrições a alterações na tabela.

Comment: por que o MySQL tem essa restrição? - Otimizacao, evita que a subquery faça um select em uma row vazia (um dos fatores no mysql)

Comment: Postgres nao tem essa restriçao, e oracle e outros nao sei informar